# How to change conditional PHP if-phrase to JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I had a product grid that originally was written in PHP. But I've changed it to AJAX and get the results in JSON and have turned that to JS variables.

Now I need to write the whole HTML structure as a JS string to attach it with jQuery. But I'm having difficulties with this one:

```
<? if(isset($mv['jan_code']) AND $mv['jan_code']!=''){ ?>
    <td>JAN Code</td><td>"+post_meta['jan_code']+"</td>
<? }?>
```

`$mv['jan_code']` is the following JS string: `post_meta['jan_code']`.

**How can I rewrite this PHP if-phrase in JS?**

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but this is how I'm thinking of outputting my JSON results:

```
var fill_grid_json = function(data){
    var jsonData=$.parseJSON(data); //change here
        $.each(jsonData, function(i) {

// get JS variables
var id = jsonData[i].ID;
var post_title = jsonData[i].post_title;
var post_meta = jsonData[i].post_meta;

var grid_item = "<tr>"+
            "<td>" + id + "</td>"+
            "<td>" + post_title + "</td>"+
            "</tr>";
            $(grid_item).appendTo("#testajax tbody");
        });
};
```

Comment: show your JSON please

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: You try replacing PHP `isset()` with JS `typeof(post_meta['jan_code']) !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one of the ways is just creating a JS string like this:

```
if(post_meta['jan_code'] != ''){
    var spectr_jan = "<tr><td>JAN Code</td><td>"+post_meta['jan_code']+"</td></tr>";
} else { var spectr_jan=''; }
```

and then showing it somewhere using jQuery.